# Can anyone help me to write a utility that we all could use to stop /boot from becoming full?

Tags: boot, disk-utility

Can anyone help me to write a utility for Ubuntu that we all could use to stop /boot from becoming full?

I would like a utility that can either a) remove old files regularly when boot is getting full or b) be run just before Update or Upgrade to remove old files in the boot folder to avoid "lack of space" errors.

If such a utility (or maybe a similar, more generic one) already exists, please could someone point me to it (and how to use it for only the unwanted files) to avoid re-inventing the wheel.

Thanks for all helpful answers. Bill

Comment: Run `apt-get autoremove` once a month and you should be golden.

Comment: stop using a boot drive? problem solved.

Comment: Thanks muru. I'll investigate how to use that on a spare PC.

Answer (score 4):

The main reason why /boot becomes full (I suppose you have a different partition for it) are the kernel upgrades. Every time a new kernel is installed the old one does not get removed for security reasons, so you end up with multiple kernels.

You can follow the instructions from this website:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/RemoveOldKernels

It is from the official Ubuntu documentation, and explains the process of removing old kernels. It also has instructions for using a script to do it.

When you are going to remove old kernels, ALWAYS remember to KEEP:

- Your current kernel (get its name with the 'uname -r' command);
- The previous kernel.

So that you will have your current working kernel and a security version for recovery.

Also remember to regularly purge old kernels (2 in 2 months should be OK) so you clean up your /boot partition. Note that the /boot partition should have about 5GB, have you considered increasing its size?

Comment: Thanks Eduardo. I'll check that out and try some things on a spare PC.